# Kotlin Spring Boot Dependency Injection

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I'm having problem with kotlin autowired dependency injection

```
@Service
class VersionServiceImpl : VersionService {

    @Autowired
    lateinit var repository: VersionRepository

    @Autowired
    lateinit var mapper: VersionMapper


    override fun findAllVersions(): List<VersionDto> {
        val versions = repository.findAll()
        return mapper.entityListToDtoList(versions)
    }
}
```

My Applications class

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("br.com.zetait.odontofy.repository")
@EntityScan("br.com.zetait.odontofy.entity")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = [
    "br.com.zetait.odontofy.mapper",
    "br.com.zetait.odontofy.controller",
    "br.com.zetait.odontofy.repository",
    "br.com.zetait.odontofy.service"
])
class OdontofyApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<OdontofyApplication>(*args)
}
```

The error thats happen...

```
Description:

Field mapper in br.com.zetait.odontofy.service.VersionServiceImpl required a bean of type 'br.com.zetait.odontofy.mapper.VersionMapper' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'br.com.zetait.odontofy.mapper.VersionMapper' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I saw some sites that saying to use lombok with @RequireArgsConstructor, but didn't work too... Can someone help me please?

Comment: Have you annotated the `PatientMapper` as a Spring `@Component` or `@Service` or do you registered any bean of type `PatientMapper`?

Comment: I setted PatientMapper as @Component and didn't work :-(

Comment: First of all, get rid of those lateinit vars and replace them with vals in the constructor for constructor injection. Secondly start the app with -Dlogging.level.org.springframework and search the logs at start up for PatientMapper to check that the bean is created.

Comment: Are you sure that the `PatientMapper` component is detected and registered by spring boot application? If not sure use `@ComponentScan` annotation. Read more: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning

Comment: It was the @ComponentScan at the mapper package... It solved Thx